# How to do internal rewrites with NGINX from main domain to subdomain

Tags: redirect, nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to serve all my static files from subdomain rather than my original domain, i tested out this setting, I have added the following lines to the conf file for the main domain

`location ~* \.(css|jpg) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ "$scheme://static.domain.com/$1" permanent;
    }`

It is working and redirecting the css and jpgs to the subdomain, but the client is detecting it is a redirect from www.domain.com to static.domain.com, and I don't need this redirect, I like it to be seamlessly to the web clients, in other words the nginx need to do this internally without the browser detecting it.

If this can't be done through nginx, can it be done through apache or .htaccess?

Thank you.

Comment: If `static.domain.com` is on another server, you will need to reverse proxy to make it invisible to the client. See [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more.

Comment: I dont have much experience with Nginx so I am not sure what to do with proxy_pass even after reading your comment, and static.domain.com can be assigned to another IP if that is what you you mean, if you can suggest a configuration for me to test, that would be really great.